# Adding gutters in custom made gird without padding

Tags: html, css, grid, gutter

So I have been struggling with this situation. 
**The Markup**

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="col-1-4">
                <div class="module">
                    <h3>1/4</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1-2">
                <div class="module">
                    <h3>1/2</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1-4">
                <div class="module">
                    <h3>1/4</h3>
            </div>
         </div>
 </div>
```

**The CSS**

```
 *{
     box-sizing :  border-box;
 }
 [class *="col"]{
      float : left;
      height : auto;
      overflow: hidden;
 }
 .col-1-2{
      width : 50%;
 }

.col-1-4{
   width : 25%;
 }

#container{
    width : 960px;
    padding : 20px;
    margin : 10px auto 0 auto;
}

.module {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: sans-serif; 
}
```

This makes columns appear side by side properly. But the ends collapse into one another and the whole thing appears like one big rectangle.
[image]

Now, I tried faking gutters by
editing the existing CSS Style for `[class*="col"]` and adding `padding-right : 20px` to it

```
[class *="col"]{
    float : left;
    height : auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right : 20px;
}
```

Now everything looks like

[image: Image2]

I've managed to put in the gutters but if you look closely, the three grey rectangles are not centred inside the container div, they are more of pushed towards right.
[image] How to tackle this situation ? It'd be really helpful if someone suggested a better method for adding gutters. 

Thanks
(Blue highlights in the images suggest the actual sizes of columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add padding to left and right border of block

```
[class *="col"]{
    float : left;
    height : auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding : 0 10px;
}
```

and

```
#container{
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but, this causes one of the 1/4 divs to stretch and another to squash causing change in their widths.

Comment: So try just `padding:0 10px;` to your class=col and remove nth-child

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing your CSS as below

```
[class *="col"]{
    float : left;
    height : auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Add the below to your CSS

```
[class *="col"]:first-child{
     padding-left : 0px;
}
```

Comment: Though it centers the divs inside the container it effects their widths which is not desired. I mean both 1/4 divs should have the same widths, shouldn't they?